# How remove new lines from string in twig

Tags: twig

I have this code:

```
{% set pageDescription = item.description|length > 197 ? item.description|striptags|trim|slice(0, 197) ~ '...' : item.description %}
```

I will remove new lines from item.description

example I have

```
<meta name="description" content="An easy playing game about the natural numbers. There will randomly appear the natural. You have to choose what the right after number is. It&amp;#8217;s so easy to play this game, isn&amp;#8217;t it?

The..." />
```

change to

```
<meta name="description" content="An easy playing game about the natural numbers. There will randomly appear the natural. You have to choose what the right after number is. It&amp;#8217;s so easy to play this game, isn&amp;#8217;t it? The..." />
```

How I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `|replace({ "\n": "" })`?

Comment: The only correct way to do this is `{{ post.content | replace({ '\r\n': '\\r\\n', '\n': '\\n', '\r': '\\r' }) }}` in order to keep the line breaks as literals or `{{ post.content | replace({ '\r\n': '', '\n': '', '\r': '' }) }}` to remove them completely.

Answer (score 26):

Try using the [`|replace`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/replace.html) filter.

```
|replace({"\n": "", "\r": "", "\t": ""})
```

For example

```
{{ item.description|replace({"\n": "", "\r": "", "\t": ""}) }}
```

Comment: I ended up needing both the `|replace()` filter and the `{% spaceless %}` tag for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

If you need it only html tag maybe the [spaceless](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html) `{% spaceless %} ... {% endspaceless %}` would be enough

Comment: it is not ! I had to use `spaceless` and `replace` together !

Comment: With twig 3 it's `{% apply spaceless %} ... {% endapply %}`